# Including const in operator overloading argument list gives error (C++)

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying out with operator overloading, for which I wrote below code

```
class OwnClass
{
private:
    int x,y;
public:
    OwnClass(int x, int y) { SetX(x); SetY(y); }
    int GetX() { return x; }
    void SetX(int x) { this->x = x;}
    int GetY() { return y; }
    void SetY(int y) {this->y = y;}

    OwnClass& operator + (const OwnClass &o)  // Problematic line
    {
        this->x += o.GetX();
        this->y += o.GetY();

        return *this;
    }
};
```

When compiled, following error is shown

> fun.cpp(65): error C2662: 'OwnClass::GetX' : cannot convert 'this'
>   pointer from 'const OwnClass' to 'OwnClass &' 
>   Conversion loses qualifiers
>
> fun.cpp(66): error C2662: 'OwnClass::GetY' : cannot convert
>   'this' pointer from 'const OwnClass' to 'OwnClass &' Conversion loses
>   qualifiers

When I modify the code as under, it compiles fine.

```
OwnClass& operator + (OwnClass &o)  // removed const
{
    this->x += o.GetX();
    this->y += o.GetY();

    return *this;
}
```

I could not understand **why so ?** I mean I am not able to understand the compiler error.

Comment: `operator +` should be returning a new object, not the same object.  It is `operator +=` that should be returning the current object (by reference).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for that additional information !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `o` is declared as reference to `const`, which can't be called with `GetX` and `GetY`, because they're non-const member function. You can (and should) change them to const member functions to solve the issue.

```
int GetX() const { return x; }
int GetY() const { return y; }
```

BTW: In general binary `operator+` is not supposed to return a reference to non-const. It's better to return a new object by value.

```
OwnClass operator + (const OwnClass &o) const
{
    OwnClass r(GetX(), GetY());
    r.x += o.GetX();
    r.y += o.GetY();

    return r;
}
```

Note for this case `operator+` could (and should) be declared as const member function too. And as @M.M suggested, making it non-member function would be better.

Comment: Oh ! How could I miss this.. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling non-const member functions on `const` objects. Make getters `const` to fix this problem:

```
int GetX() const { return x; }
int GetY() const { return y; }
```

Comment: Oh ! How could I miss this.. Thanks !